# Extracting Cookies from different Host Java

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

Is it possible to extract cookies of different host?

Meaning.......  I developed a JSP page moving from "http://abc.com" to "http://def.com", so is it possible that cookies saved by "abc.com" can be used in "def.com"?

Comment: I suppose you send a redirect? Just add a `Set-Cookie` header, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "No".
The longer answer is "no and it is fine that it is not possible."

Cookie may contain very sensitive information. For example HTTP session ID. If you can stole cookie from other domain you can stole identity of any user. Including someone that is currently dealing with his bank account. Accessing such cookie gives you ability to perform operations on behave the use you took the cookies from. This is the reason that such activity is forbidden by browser.